# Need to find out production rules of a web site

Tags: html, ebnf

Is there a tool to generate these rules in ebnf format? Then i will do lexical analysis and syntax.

What can be used?

And these rules will be just like HTML rules, won't be?

Comment: And these rules will be just like HTML EBNF rules, won't be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you meaning to refer to W3C standards? If so, this might help you: http://www.w3.org/standards/